# Why is this mass equation giving me mass = weight when clearly it isn't?

Tags: mass, weight

Convert the weight measured in pounds to the equivalent in Newtons. In the formula for determining mass based on weight, mass is measured in Newtons. Weight is measured in Kilograms, and the acceleration of gravity on Earth is measured as 9.8 meters per second squared. These are metric system unit measurements. To find the equivalent in U.S. units, you perform conversions. One pound is equal to 4.44822162 Newtons. Therefore, to convert pounds to Newtons, multiply the weight in pounds by 4.44822162. For example, to convert 150 lbs to Newtons, calculate as follows: 150 x 4.44822162 = 667 Newtons.

Divide the weight in Newtons by the acceleration of gravity to determine the mass of an object measured in Kilograms. On Earth, gravity accelerates at 9.8 miles per second squared (9.8 m/s2). For example, to determine the mass of an object weighing 667 Newtons, calculate as follows: 667 Newtons / 9.8 m/s2 = 68 kilograms.

Convert the mass measured in kilograms to the mass in pounds. One kilogram is equal to 2.20462262 pounds. Therefore, to convert kilograms to pounds, multiply the kilogram value by 2.20462262. For example: 68 kilograms x 2.20462262 = 150 pounds.

This obviously is not right because 2 things that weigh the same can have a different mass. What is wrong with this conversion?

Comment: 'mass is measured in Newton. Weight is measured in Kilograms' - no, it's the other way around, mass is in kg, weight is in Newton. Your weight changes when you go to the moon (smaller g), your mass doesn't

Comment: Are you sure you don't start with mass in kg and weight in N, instead of the other way around?

Comment: It is weight in pounds converted to newtons, divided by the force of gravity to get kilograms, and then kilograms to pounds and it starts with 150 and ends with 150

Comment: Obviously thats not right because different things with the same weight have different mass

Comment: Different things in different conditions can have same weight but different mass, but if measured in similar conditions they will not have the same weight if mass is different. You seem to be confused with these two terms.

Comment: Compare wikipedia definitions of [weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight) and [mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass).

Comment: on earth two things that way 1 pound have a different mass because of 2 things:

Comment: Those are the molecules inside them and the density of those molecules. Thus 2 things that weigh the same thing on the same planet or moon can have a different mass

Comment: *"on earth two things that way 1 pound have a different mass"* No, you can't. Newton specifies the relationship $F = ma$, where the role of acceleration ($a$) is taken by gravity $g \approx 32 \,\mathrm{ft/s^2} \approx 10 \,\mathrm{m/s^2}$. Same weight implies same mass and *vice versa*. Allow the possibility of different gravities and things change.

Comment: but you also have to consider molecular weight of all the molecules and the density to get true mass.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: (1) Work only in SI until you are very clear about this (the traditional English units predate a precise scientific understanding and are often used poorly). (2) Understand weight and mass *before* you start asking about molecular composition. (3) Be aware that *old* terms (like "molecular weight") may be have incorrect semantics compare to modern usage; many texts use "molecular mass" now because it is more precise. (4) Units, units, unit. If you write down the *units* you can't get it wrong (again, stick to SI until you are clear on this, English units are irrational).

Comment: english units are not irrational. You might get a repeating decimal dividing metric by english but never an irrational number proving that english is never irrational.

Comment: ^That makes no sense at all. @caters, you're getting weight, mass, density and volume confused. Weight is the force gravity exerts on mass. For a given object, its mass is constant. The weight changes depending on the acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: I am american and You ought to know that. Also take the density of butter and the density of water. they have different densities, in fact the butter is more dense. Now a 1 pound stick of butter and a pint of water have a different volume and density. The butter has more molecules per in^3. That means that because density has mass and volume that butter has more mass but has the same weight which is actually true.

Comment: A pound of butter and a pint of water have the same mass if you've measured their weight at the same point on the surface of the earth. They do have different densities, and therefore will occupy different volumes, but their mass is the same.

Comment: but again butter has more molecules per in^3 and they are more complex molecules so it would make sense from that perspective that a scale that measures mass and not weight when the weight is 1 pound for butter the mass is greater than it is for 1 pint of water, thus they would not balance on a triple beam balance even if the weight was exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing called a "slug". " It is a mass that accelerates by 1 ft/s2 when a force of one pound-force (lbF) is exerted on it." (wikipedia).

Sometimes you'll see reference to a "pound-mass" to indicate a mass which weighs one pound at sea level (on Earth, thank you!  :-) ).

The problem is that pounds and kilograms have been used colloquially since forever to describe the weight of objects.  Scientific usage differs from informal usage such as "shipping weight".

Comment: Don't forget poundals ...

Comment: There is also a dyne.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that one pound-force is *not* a pound. A pound-force is a *force* while a pound is a *mass*.

A pound-force has [Imperial units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) of
$$
1\,{\rm lbf}=1\,{\rm slug\cdot\,\frac{ft}{s^2}}
$$
where [**slug**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28mass%29) is the Imperial unit of mass.

One *pound* is equal to 0.45359237 kilograms, thus 150 lbs = 68 kg as you expect when doing the conversions.

Comment: we use pounds, tons, ounces all the time when we talk about weight and we are referring to actual weight and not mass.

Comment: @caters: [Not really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass))

Comment: when we weigh a truck with its load to know if it is oversized load, we don't factor out the gravity, we just look at what the scale says and the scale doesn't factor out gravity either.

Comment: @caters Scales don't read forces, they read *masses*. When we *say* "weight" (as in "I weigh 150 lbs), we are using the *colloquial* term that means mass, not the *science* term that means force.

Comment: No they read mass * gravity. They know that there is gravity and so they register weight not mass. and again weight and mass are not equal and a good example of that is a 1 pound baby doll vs 1 pound of butter. The 1 pound of butter has only fat and a certain density. The doll on the other hand has lots of organic molecules more complex than fat so overall the doll has more mass than the butter but have the same weight.

Comment: The distinction between pounds-force and pounds-mass has no basis in deep history and had to be applied as physics developed and it's usage has not been consistent. In particular the idea that mass is the default and force has to be specified is not fully uniform; there are those who do it the other way 'round. Safest to always say which one you mean.

Comment: Kyle, what scales are sensitive to and what they are calibrated in are distinct ideas. Spring scales and strain-gauge transducers devices are sensitive to force. Balance style scales (two-pan and beam-types) are (assuming locally constant gravity, but independent of what that gravity *is*) sensitive to mass. Either type can be scaled in the other unit by assuming a gravity.

Comment: @caters They don't even read mass*gravity, since they read the net force exerted on the scale. So you have to take into account bouyancy too. And why does the doll have more mass? I think that's wrong.

Comment: more complex molecules of sugars from any plant fibers + other complex organic compounds makes the 1 pound doll have more mass than the butter which is basically just fatty acids + water with no aldehydes or ketones or alcohols or any of the rest of those organic compounds. Plus 2 different masses here on Earth can weigh the same and vice versa. It all depends on the complexity of the compounds in it and how much of that space is taken up by air.

Comment: The slug is not the Imperial unit of mass. The pound (mass) is. The slug is a rather recent invention, ~100 years old, younger than that in common engineering usage. Compare with the pound mass and pound force. The pound (no distinction between mass and force) is very, very old. The distinction between pound mass and pound force is  at least 300 years old.